# easy_localization code generation process is not getting through from Android Studio Terminal

Tags: android, flutter, dart, localization, flutter-localizations

After setting up all the `.json` files, `pubspec` file and initialization in the main method when I am trying to create the `codegen_loader.g.dart` file from the terminal by invoking `flutter pub run easy_localization:generate`, it's not getting through. Even no error message is getting.

Below is a snippet of the command line:

```
PS C:\Users\Prosanto\Desktop\Android Dev\localization> flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -h

PS C:\Users\Prosanto\Desktop\Android Dev\localization> flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -S "assets/translations" -O "lib/translations"

PS C:\Users\Prosanto\Desktop\Android Dev\localization>
```

Nothing is happening, any help or suggestion is highly helpful.

Comment: In the end did you achieve to fix the problem?

Answer (score 6):

I dealt with this same issue on Mac, but these steps should still help.

First, I ran this command from the Mac terminal, not from Android Studio (whether that made any difference, who knows, but it wasn't working when running from the IDE). It's different from the easy_localization docs

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate --source-dir assets/translations
```

After that, I ran this command:

```
flutter pub run easy_localization:generate -S assets/translations -f keys -o locale_keys.g.dart
```

And the necessary files were generated as expected. I hope this helps!

Comment: you saved my day! worked on Mac!